# How to correctly use beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a few general questions about beautifulsoup:

1. when I want to use the findAll method and find when `class="pie"` in the HTML code how would I do that? Class is already a method (I think that is what it is called) in python. It gives me an error when I try it. However, when I try an example like `align="center"` it works perfectly fine
2. very similar question;If i want to find a specific type of meta tag; like for ex `<div class="pies"...>` how would i do that? `findAll("dir class="pies"")`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`class` is a keyword in Python, so you can't do:

```
soup.find_all('div', class='pie')
```

Add an underscore at the end of the keyword argument and it'll work:

```
soup.find_all('div', class_='pie')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to specify properties in a dictionary as the 2nd argument. For example:

```
soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'content'} )
soup.find('div', {'id': 'content'} )
soup.find('meta', { 'property': 'og:image'} )
```

In your case, you can just do

```
soup.findAll('div', { 'class': 'pie'} )
```